# Book about a planet covered in very, very long necked aliens

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a sci-fi story where astronauts visit a planet, which is covered in stationary aliens with mile long necks that filter feed from the atmosphere.

It was published between 1960 and 2000.

It was in English and involved a pair of astronauts that went from planet to planet on a tour or something, though I don't know details of any other planets they visited.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I'm getting a mental image similar to the cover art for Blue Oyster Cult's album *Cultosaurus Erectus*...

Comment: @ZeissIkon that actually looks almost exactly like how the aliens are described in the novel

Comment: Any idea what length story (short, novella, novel), where published?  In English?

Comment: @ZeissIkon It was not a short story.

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244217/early-1980s-graphic-novel-about-human-spies-undercover-on-an-intergalactic-cruis (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "A Tour Of The Universe" by Robert Holdstock and Malcolm Edwards.
It is a book of science fiction art strung together by a story of a tourist couple who won a tour of the universe from some interstellar cruise line.

Here's a picture from the book of those long necked filter-feeding aliens you mentioned.

[image: filter feeding alien]

Comment: Interesting.  So that part of the story was written around Richard Clifton-Dey's painting.  I wonder whether the artwork was first intended for this book or for the cover of the Blue Oyster Cult album *Cultösaurus Erectus*?  (Both came out in 1980.)

Comment: I vaguely remember that book.  The rest of the art might also have been by Clifton-Dey.  If so, the approximately simultaneous appearance on the album was probably a coincidence.